# Anyone experiencing Error code -46 on Java SDK 1.20

Tags: philips-hue

Latest Java SDK (1.20) seems to throw NoSuchMethodError when trying to autheticate with the accesspoint using onAuthenticationRequired() ;  Once the exception is thrown then all subsequent attempt to connect to the bridge will result in " Error - Code 46 Message bridge not responding"

Anyone experiencing this behaviour,  code is executed on

```
java version "1.6.0_27"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.8) (6b27-1.12.8)

OpenJDK Zero VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)




Exception in thread "Thread-25" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Integer.compare(II)I
 at com.philips.lighting.hue.sdk.fbp.PHBridgeVersionManager$1.compare(PHBridgeVersionManager.java:83)
 at com.philips.lighting.hue.sdk.fbp.PHBridgeVersionManager$1.compare(PHBridgeVersionManager.java:1)
 at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1283)
 at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1294)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1223)
 at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:176)
 at com.philips.lighting.hue.sdk.fbp.PHBridgeVersionManager.setFallbackBridgeVersion(PHBridgeVersionManager.java:130)
 at com.philips.lighting.hue.sdk.fbp.PHBridgeVersionManager.setBridgeVersion(PHBridgeVersionManager.java:365)
 at com.philips.lighting.hue.sdk.connection.impl.PHBridgeInternal.processResponse(PHBridgeInternal.java:450)
 at com.philips.lighting.hue.sdk.connection.impl.PHBridgeInternal$1.run(PHBridgeInternal.java:122)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Integer.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)) was introduced in Java 7 and you're clearly using Java 6 based on the error message.

Try using Java 7 or Java 8.